# How to replace word in text with link (Pug)?

Tags: string, replace, pug

I am a very beginner in Pug and I'm trying to solve the following task: Every occurrence (in text) of the following words shall become a link to the destination defined below:

sed -> https://google.com
 liq -> https://facebook.com

Тhis works as I expected, but keeps anchor tag as string.

```
- var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pulvinar elementum integer sed neque volutpat ac. Facilisis liq odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean . Vel facilisis volutpat liq velit. Viverra aliquet liq sit amet tellus cras adipiscing sed.";
- var url = '#[a(href="https://google.com") sed]'; //I tried with these ones too - var url = '<a href="https://google.com">sed</a>'; var url = 'a(href="https://google.com)sed'
- var res = str.replace(/sed/g, url);

p #{res}


Here my latest atempt:

mixin link(href, name)
  a(href=href target!=attributes.target )= name

//+link('https://google.com', 'Google')(target="blank")

- var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Pulvinar elementum integer sed neque volutpat ac. Facilisis liq odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean . Vel facilisis volutpat liq velit. Viverra aliquet liq sit amet tellus cras adipiscing sed.";
- var link = +link('https://google.com', 'Google')(target="blank");
- var res = str.replace(/sed/g, link);

p #{res}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen Pug mixins used within javascript code blocks like that before. I'm surprised it even outputs the anchor tag at all.

That being said, you can use the [unescaped string interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped) syntax (`!{variable}`) instead of the regular string interpolation syntax (`#{variable}`) to get the link to render as a link.

In your case:

```
p !{res}
```

But keep in mind this word of warning from the [Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped):

> **Caution**
>
> Keep in mind that buffering unescaped content into your templates can be mighty risky if that content comes fresh from your users. Never trust user input!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work. By the way, the first code returns an anchor tag and the second NaN.

Comment: Is it outputting an html anchor tag, or the pug shorthand anchor tag?

Comment: It is outputting this: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, #[a(href="https://google.com") sed] do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Comment: Ah ok, that's the Pug shorthand. I misunderstood originally, and my answer isn't going to solve your issue.

Comment: Pug isn't great for dynamically parsing and modifying text server-side. I'd recommend adding the Pug anchor links manually if possible, or programmatically before the string is passed to Pug.

Comment: If I use - var url = '<a href="https://google.com">sed</a>'; instead - var url = '#[a(href="https://google.com") sed]'; and than I write  unescaped string interpolation  p !{res}, as you told me, it works. Thank you!